# Use Range created by Union Command in a formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range that has been created using the Union command. I want the range created by this Union in a formula where I sum all values in the range. Everything I have tried comes up with errors.

Code for how my range is created.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xRg In .Range("N1:N" & lastrow)
        If UCase(xRg.Text) = 1 Then
            If yRg Is Nothing Then
                Set yRg = .Range("C" & xRg.Row).Resize(, 1)
            Else
                Set yRg = Union(yRg, .Range("C" & xRg.Row).Resize(, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next xRg
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

If Not yRg Is Nothing Then yRg.Select
```

I now want to use `yRg` in a sum.

Comment: and have you tried this one `WorksheetFunction.sum(yRg)`? what error you get?

Comment: Show the code that you have used in trying to use this range with a sum. It doesn't make a lot of sense to not show the code which has the bug you are trying to solve but instead show code which you claim works okay.

Comment: "comes up with errors" doesn't tell us anything; there are countless types of errors, each for a different reason.  There is a reason for error codes and descriptions.  Have you tried researching the errors?

Comment: Have you tried using  `=WorksheetFunction.Sum(yRg)` ?

Comment: what about using `SUMIF()` ? Simple...

Comment: Are you sure `yRg` actually has anything set to it?

Comment: @ShaiRado Just to clarify, is `.Value` optional in this construction?

Comment: @AntiDrondert it's safer to use `Range("A1").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(yRg)`

Comment: As a couple of others have said - use `WorksheetFunction.SUM(yRG)`.  Are you sure you want to use `UCase(xRg.Text)` though?  That will look at what's visible in the cell - if the column is too narrow it could see nothing, or `#####`.... just noticed @ShaiRado is suggesting something similar (use value or just `Ucase(xRg)=1`)

Comment: Thanks Shai Radio your suggestion Range("A1").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(yRg), gave me want I was wanting for my code.